# Bluemix Pipeline Deployment Envirorment variables for APP

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, ibm-jazz, devops-services

IBM deleted my GIT repos and pipelines... this guys are crazy...

Now my deployments are brokens. And now my pipelines dosn't exists. I don't remember how I created the custom instrucctions 2 years ago.

How I can create custom vars in the deployment custom script in my NodeJS app?

I use pipeline deployment for create 3 envirorments, and I need custom vars in each envirorment APP.

This not works:

```
#!/bin/bash
cf push "${CF_APP}" --no-start
cf set-env "${CF_APP}" APP_ENVIRONMENT "QA"
cf restage "${CF_APP}"
```

I need to add something for install dependencies like npm install?
I need to add something about that I want use NodeJS and the version?
I need to put this in some order?

In custom server is simple, after install nodejs you do npm install && node app, end. In Bluemix errors everywhere.

Comment: This is a complaint - not a question. If you "lost" your Git repository (not sure how that happens), and your pipelines, then open a ticket with support to recover them.

Comment: Do your issues stem from the publicly announced retirement of the Delivery Pipeline service on April 25, 2017, which took effect on July 5th? See: 
https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/04/delivery-pipeline-retirement/

Comment: can you provide more information on how you have setup your pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup separate deploy stages to deploy to 3 environments. Please refer to the [documentation on delivery pipeline](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/ContinuousDelivery/pipeline_deploy_var.html#deliverypipeline_environment) on how to add configuration properties.

BTW, would you mind dropping an email to hub at jazz.net with the URL of your Git repo that you believe has been deleted? Thanks!